# How to replication Connection reset by peer in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, connection-reset

In my production environment I got the following error in my server:

```
 Cannot forward to error page for request [/api/validation] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

Now I created a client and produced 1000 thread every second to call this `[/api/validation]`.
The error I got was

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9954" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:7080/v1/name/validate": Timeout waiting for connection from pool; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool.
```

Now I want to know is what is the cause of `Connection reset by peer` .

According to what I know is this error occurs when the client aborts the connection by sending the RST packet.
I set the socket Timeout of my client's rest template to 9000. I make the server sleep for about 15000 MS. Now shouldn't the server get `Connection reset by peer` as the server tries to send the response after 15 seconds and my client just waits for about 9 seconds. Shouldn't I get the error?

Also in the production environment the wait time (Rest template socket time out) for the client is set to about a 90 seconds ( more than the time the server requires to response). Why is the error being produced in the production?